# Yield string from recursive function

Tags: python, tkinter, recursion, yield

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def periodically_called():
    yield "Hello"

    root.after(1000*sleep, i for i in periodically_called())

for i in periodically_called():
    print(i)
```

I am trying to print the string from a recursive function. How do I go about this?

Comment: What happened when you ran this code? Did you get the result that you expected? Did you get a different result? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Your code failed to run with exception `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized` on the line `root.after(...)`.